# Where can I find a Welsh word list?

Tags: dictionary, aspell

I am looking for a Welsh language word list on my Ubuntu system. `apt-file search /usr/share/dict/` doesn't show an option. However [aspell-cy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aspell-cy) does exist. The official description is "This package contains all the required files to add support for the Welsh language to the GNU Aspell spell checker." I have installed it but can't find the word list it should be using.

Where can I find a Welsh language word list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the details of how `aspell` works, but it looks like it has its word lists in some binary format and not as simple text files. I believe you are looking for a file called `cy.cwl`.

I downloaded the tar.gz file from your launchpad link, decompressed it and ran `./configure` and then `make`:

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/aspell-cy/0.50-3-6.2/aspell-cy_0.50-3.orig.tar.gz 2>/dev/null 
$ tar xvzf aspell-cy_0.50-3.orig.tar.gz 
aspell-cy-0.50-3/
aspell-cy-0.50-3/doc/
aspell-cy-0.50-3/doc/gpl_1.0.txt
aspell-cy-0.50-3/info
aspell-cy-0.50-3/cy.multi
aspell-cy-0.50-3/README
aspell-cy-0.50-3/configure
aspell-cy-0.50-3/Copyright
aspell-cy-0.50-3/cy.dat
aspell-cy-0.50-3/cy.cwl
aspell-cy-0.50-3/welsh.alias
aspell-cy-0.50-3/Makefile.pre
aspell-cy-0.50-3/COPYING
$ cd aspell-cy-0.50-3/
$ ./configure 
Finding Dictionary file location ... /usr/lib/aspell-0.60
Finding Data file location ... /usr/lib/aspell-0.60
$ make
word-list-compress d < cy.cwl | aspell  --lang=cy create master ./cy.rws
```

The command printed by `make` looked like it was decompressing (`d`) something and then passing it to `aspell` to create the `cy` language entry. And, indeed, running the first part of the command printed out the Welsh dictionary:

```
 $ word-list-compress d < cy.cwl | head -n30
'ch
'i
'm
'ma
'n
'na
'r
'th
'u
'w
Aberdaugleddyf
Abergwaun
Aberhonddu
Abermo
Abertawe
Aberteifi
Adda
Adfent
Affrig
Ahasferus
Aifft
Ailfedyddiwr
Ailfedyddwyr
Alban
Albanwr
Albanwyr
Almaen
Almaenaidd
Almaeneg
Almaenes
```

So, either do what I did above, or just `locate cy.cwl` on your system, and then:

```
word-list-compress d < cy.cwl > welsh.dict
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried exactly the same steps with aspell-ru  but I get word-list-compress d < ru.cwl
ERROR: Corrupt Input.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Anush you're welcome. I added a comment to your new question, but I am not an expert on aspell and its formats. I only found out what I have in my answer yesterday when I tried to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I added that the information you mentioned to my other question.